# What changed between these two docker versions to change volume permissions?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    image: node:11
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src"
    working_dir: "/usr/src"
# ...
```

On my mac, I have Docker 18.09. On our jenkins build server I have Docker 1.10.

If I run the following on both machines

```
docker-compose run foo mkdir hello
```

On the mac it creates a folder with my user's ownership, on the build server it creates a folder with root's ownership. If I run `ls -l` on each:

```sh
ls -l # After folder created with Docker 18.09 on Mac
...
drwxr-xr-x   2 my_user       my_group      64 Dec 19 00:10 hello
...

ls -l # After folder created with Docker 1.10 on Jenkins machine
...
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          64 Dec 19 00:10 hello
...
```

I understand that in the earlier version, the directory is created using docker's `root` account and is given permissions with the `uid` and `gid` of 0. What I don't understand is why this doesn't happen any more with the more modern version.

I’ve tried/discounted a few work arounds:

I've seen plenty of examples online that suggest setting the `user` field in the compose to the id of the user on the host machine. Unfortunately that is causing permission problems with certain scripts that seem to expect to be running as root and isn't particularly portable.

Also, we unfortunately won't be able to upgrade the version of Docker on the local machine for a little while, so the solution needs to be available to v 1.10, and have as little impact for other users of the docker engine as possible (which I think makes user-namespaces a little bit more difficult, but I don't exactly understand them so I might be mistaken).

My question, what has changed between the two versions of Docker to change this behavior, and is there anything I can do to make the earlier behave like the later? Created files and directories should be given the host user's ownership instead of root's.

Comment: I think it was a security issue. It is not really a good idea to allow containers do stuff with root access anyway. Docker engine has changed a great deal until now, so maybe consider updating to 1.10?

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş Sorry, do you mean updating from 1.10? The build server is 1.10 already, but unfortunately the version we use there is something that is out of my hands.

Comment: Yeah from 1.10. my bad. Also it is not Jenkins who creates the directory right?

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş correct. The directory is being created in by docker and shared across the volume with `docker-compose run foo mkdir hello`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MacOS, you have osxfs which maps file permissions in a way that relatively transparent to the user mounting volumes:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/

Directly on Linux, volumes are mounted with the same uid/gid in the container and in the host. If you run applications as a different user inside the container, my solution is to start the container as root, modify the container user to match the volume mount permissions, and then su to that user to run the app. Scripts to do this and a full example are at:

https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base

If you run your application as root in the container, then it will create files as root in the volume on Linux. I'm not aware of any simple workarounds to this.

Comment: Oh, so this difference comes from the OS (and docker-for-mac) not something that's changed between versions of Docker?

Comment: @SCB I believe so. Mac has some features of filesystem sharing into the embedded Linux VM that you don't have when running directly on Linux. Similar features exist with VirtualBox. The fix-perms script that I use in my repo handles many of the other situations, including things like the docker.sock file on Mac since that doesn't exist outside the VM.